# Consumir RaiseEvent no funciona

Tags: vb.net, eventos

con vb.net
tengo 2 programas diferentes, las cuales quiero que se comuniquen por medio de eventos de una capa intermedia

capa intermedia

```
Public Class Eventos

Public Event Nueva(ByRef ID As Integer)

Public Sub Nueva(id As Integer)
    RaiseEvent Nueva(id)
End Sub
End Class
```

desde uno de los programas llamo al metodo para lanzar el evento

```
Dim eventos As New PCPO200.Eventos
eventos.Nueva(ID)
```

y desde el segundo programa lo capturo

```
Private WithEvents eventos As PCPO200.Eventos
Private Sub eventos_Nueva(ByRef ID As Integer) Handles eventos.Nueva

    MsgBox(ID)
End Sub
```

pero el segundo programa nunca recibe el evento. algo estoy haciendo mal?
gracias saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no le falta un new a PCPO200.Eventos? si no, no hay clase todavia...

Comment: hola @gbianchi , gracias por responder, le agrege el new anteriormente y tampoco recibe el evento

Comment: Ahh lo que pasa es que son dos clases diferentes. Tengo mis dudas de que lo que vos queres se haga asi. Vos queres que dos programas se hablen entre ellos? El evento es local a la clase.. generar otra clase en otro lado y sobre todo en otro programa distinto no va a hacer que vea ese evento, simplemente porque no funcionan de esa forma las clases.

Comment: @gbianchi son 2 proyectos diferentes, 2 .exe diferentes

Comment: Entonces no, no podes usar directamente eventos de esa forma. Necesitas algun metodo para comunicar procesos. Los eventos, salvo que sean eventos del sistema operativo, son del programa que los levanta.

Comment: @gbianchi gracias, alguna idea de comunciacion?

Comment: depende lo que tengas que hacer exactamente (entiendo que lo que pusiste aca es solo un ejemplo). fijate por ejemplo [aca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615105/best-way-to-communicate-between-2-net-apps) y fijate en la etiqueta IPC

Comment: @gbianchi gracias